# mechanize: Why does my form list only contain 1 element?

Tags: python, forms, mechanize

I'm new to mechanize and also not the most advanced python user, but I want to automize a task in which I want to give a webpage an input. Problem is now, that the "submit" Button has no control name assigned to it. So I researched a bit and found a way to set a value to the form in question. But to do this I have to access the specific form I want to assign a value to. So my code looks like this:

```
forms = [f for f in br.forms()]
print forms[0].controls[0].name
```

I just thought I could access the form by write `forms[x]` and then something like:

```
forms[x].set_value("VALUE", 
                       nr=5)
```

The error I get is:

```
    forms[54].set_value("VALUE",nr=100)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This might be a bit of a stupid question and possibly arises from the fact that I don't really understand the functions I'm using but since there is no real documentary I would really appreciate a sentence of help here.

PS: I can print all the forms using

```
for f in br.forms():
    print f
```

with output:

```
 <CheckboxControl(lookup=[yes])>
  <TextControl(fld=NoName)>
  <TextControl(pixemail=)>
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>
  <TextControl(ra=00 00 00.0)>
  <TextControl(dec=00 00 00.0)>
  <SelectControl(equinox=[*J2000.0, B1950.0])>
  <TextControl(offra=0.0)>
  <TextControl(offdec=0.0)>
  <TextControl(epoch=2000.0)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>= Retrieve Data ) (readonly)>
  <RadioControl(cextract=[*rect, circle])>
  <TextControl(rawid=10.0)>
  <TextControl(decwid=10.0)>
  <SelectControl(wunits=[Degrees, *Minutes, Seconds])>
  <TextControl(cirrad=10.0)>
  <SelectControl(cat=[UCAC 2, UCAC 3, NOMAD, *USNO B1.0, USNO A2.0, ACT])>
  <SelectControl(surims=[None, *All Surveys, POSS-I (103aO, 103aE), POSS-II (IIIaJ, IIIaF, IV-N), SOUTH, AAO-R, POSS-IO, POSS-IE, POSS-IIJ, POSS-IIF, POSS-IIN, SRC-J, SERC-EJ, ESO-R, SERC-ER])>
  <CheckboxControl(getcat=[*yes])>
  <CheckboxControl(getfin=[*yes])>
  <CheckboxControl(pixflg=[yes])>
  <CheckboxControl(colbits=[All, *cb_id, *cb_altid, *cb_ra, *cb_sigra, cb_mep, *cb_mura, cb_muprob, *cb_smura, cb_sfitra, *cb_fitpts, cb_err, *cb_flg, *cb_mag, cb_smag, *cb_mflg, *cb_fldid, *cb_sg, cb_xres, cb_pltidx, *cb_xi, *cb_dstctr, *cb_gall])>
  <RadioControl(skey=[*ra, dec, sigra, sigdec, mep, mura, mudec, muprob, smura, smudec, sfitra, sfitdec, fitpts, err, flg, mag, smag, mflg, fldid, sg, xres, yres, pltidx, clr, sigpos, mutot, sigmu, xi, eta, dstctr, gall, galb])>
  <SelectControl(slf=[*hh/dd mm ss, hh/dd:mm:ss, hh.hhh/dd.ddd, ddd.ddd/dd.ddd])>
  <TextControl(minnpts=0)>
  <TextControl(maxnpts=10)>
  <SelectControl(clr=[B1, R1, B2, *R2, I2, B, V, R, J, H, K])>
  <TextControl(bri=0)>
  <TextControl(fai=100)>
  <SelectControl(clr0m1A=[B1, R1, *B2, R2, I2, B, V, R, J, H, K])>
  <SelectControl(clr0m1B=[B1, R1, B2, *R2, I2, B, V, R, J, H, K])>
  <TextControl(bmrmin=-100)>
  <TextControl(bmrmax=100)>
  <TextControl(minposnerr=0.0)>
  <TextControl(maxposnerr=10000.0)>
  <TextControl(mumin=0.0)>
  <TextControl(mumax=10000.0)>
  <TextControl(minmuerr=0.0)>
  <TextControl(maxmuerr=10000.0)>
  <TextControl(minsep=0.0)>
  <HiddenControl(minmagerr=0.0) (readonly)>
  <HiddenControl(maxmagerr=1.0) (readonly)>
  <SelectControl(opstars=[Yes, *No])>
  <SelectControl(whorbl=[Light Stars/Dark Sky, *Dark Stars/Light Sky])>
  <SelectControl(pixgraph=[Progressive JPEG, *JPEG, GIF, PDF, Large JPEG (1 Survey Only), Large GIF (1 Survey Only), PS (1 Survey Only)])>
  <SelectControl(pixfits=[Yes, *No])>
  <SelectControl(ori=[NE - North Up, East Right, *NW - North Up, East Left, SE - North Down, East Right, SW - North Down, East Left, EN - East Up, North Right, ES - East Up, North Left, WN - East Down, North Right, WS - East Down, North Left])>
  <SelectControl(tck=[N and E marks, *Tick Marks, Grid Lines])>
  <SelectControl(starlbl=[Yes, *No])>
  <SelectControl(cmrk=[*None, 5.0 sec Box, 10.0 sec Box, 30.0 sec Box, 1.0 min Box, 2.0 min Box, 5.0 min Box, 10.0 min Box, 5.0 sec Circle, 10.0 sec Circle, 30.0 sec Circle, 1.0 min Circle, 2.0 min Circle, 5.0 min Circle, 10.0 min Circle])>
  <TextControl(aobj=none)>
  <SelectControl(pcl=[*P - Points, L - Points + Labels, C - Connected Points, A - Connected Points + Labels])>
  <TextareaControl(atbl=  )>
  <IgnoreControl(<None>=<None>)>
  <SubmitControl(<None>= Retrieve Data ) (readonly)>
  <SelectControl(gzf=[*Yes, No])>
  <SelectControl(cftype=[*ASCII, XML/VO])>>
```

The one I want to get my hands on is the `<SubmitControl(<None>=Retrieve Data ) (readonly)>`, which is the third one counted from bottom to top.

Comment: You don't need the button to submit a form. Would that solve your issue or do you really need to set that value?

Comment: Without counting all of the forms, is it possible that there simply aren't 54 of them? You can't add to a list by indexing `lst[len(lst)] = item`, you need to `lst.append(item)`.

Comment: It also doesn't work for form[1]...

Comment: @Hal: No I just need to submit a form... Is there then an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

# Insert the desired URL here
br.open('http://www.nofs.navy.mil/data/fchpix/cfch.html#fchmenu')
br.select_form(nr=0)

br["ra"] = "input 1"
br["dec"] = "input 2"
br["pixfits"] = ["Yes"]

br.find_control("pixflg").items[0].selected=True

response = br.submit()
```

Comment: Okay, that's strange... When I write:                             forms = [f for f in br.forms()];                             form=forms[0];
form.set_value("Retrieve Data",nr=54);
It says: "AttributeError: control 'None' is readonly".                   But when I run your code it says: "mechanize._mechanize.FormNotFoundError: no form matching nr 54"

Comment: You don't need it, it simply uses the index of the forms in the DOM. The first form will have index 0, the second will have an index of 1, the third 3, etc...

Comment: Check if the index is correct. I wrote 54 because it appears to be the ID of the form you want, but check it anyway because it should work out of the box.

Comment: Well... Basically it does work with what I wrote in my first comment to your answer, so the ID is indeed correct... Furthermore I can choose whatever ID I want and every time I get "no form matching nr x". Here's the webpage, if this helps: http://www.nofs.navy.mil/data/fchpix/cfch.html#fchmenu .Anyway, thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: So that means that I'm completely stupid or that the page is strange?

Comment: Ahh, got it. So, you've only got one form (that's why the 54 gives a Form Not Found error). You've got a lot of controls though. Do you want to change the value of an input field? Or is the form good to go as soon as you load the page? If you were doing this task manually what would you need to do?

Comment: Yes I want to change the two "CENTER" fields (RA and DEC),the "Rectangle size", check the "Image" box and "Also return fits" should be yes....

Comment: Just edited the response. I tested it over here, seems to do the trick. I've no idea what to put in RA and DEC, but I think you now know how to fill these fields. The idea is attribute the name property of the desired field in br["<id>"] to a string and then to submit the form

Comment: Tank you very much! Right now I cant test it but I will try it out this evening and write you back wether it works or not!

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite certain there is a better way to do this - but I'm not at all familiar with Mechanize. You *could* do something like:

```
submit_values = filter(lambda x: 'SubmitControl' in str(x), br.forms())
if submit_values:
    print(submit_values[0])
```

If there are more than one, obviously you'll get more than one. This is probably *the* weirdest way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do. Also, assuming this form is fairly static, you could replace the use of Mechanize with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/). Then it would look something like this:

```
import requests

r = requests.post("http://form/action/url/goes/here", data={"lookup": "yes",
                                                            # all the other elements
                                                            })
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
# Do something else with r.text, e.g. scrape values with beautifulsoup or something
```

Comment: Thank you... I tried your first suggestion but it just returns me the same output I quoted above... Any Idea what I'm missing here?EDIT: I also have to assign some values but not to the "Retrieve Data" Button... And looking at this issue I just wonder why I can't access any form. Only possible choice is forms[0]... Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

try this.  You can search for a control without a name by the type of control.  Just going from memory it would be:

```
br.form.find_control(type='submit', nr=1)
```

I think thats the right syntax.. I'll double check and be sure.